# 555 Astable Multivibrator Voltage Spikes

Tags: pwm, 555, astable

I built a 12V LED dimmer based on (modified from) the circuit below.
[image: Circuit]

Essentially I used a TIP31C instead of the Darlington pair, and provide power to 555 with 7805.

An oscilloscope gave me the waveform with some nasty voltage spikes.
[image: Voltage spikes]

I noticed that a newbie forgot to get capacitors before and after the voltage regulator. Is that the cause of the spikes?

Comment: Where in the circuit are you measuring this waveform?

Comment: At pin 3 before the 1k resistor, sir.

Comment: Adding a small capacitor (1nF or something like that) from pin 3 to ground will maybe make those spikes go away, but that's no explanation as to where they come from. Can you use a 10x probe? Sometimes things get messy because of you actually measuring.

Comment: Not sure if have one. Need to revisit the lab that offers me access to the oscope. But thanks for your opinion!

Comment: Are you using the clip-lead with the scope probe? The inductance of the ground lead can easily cause little, ultra-fast transients like that, if you have very fast edges.

Comment: I used one with a small hook attached (like an adaptor) to a needle. As for the negative lead, it's a alligator clip.

Comment: A picture of the real circuit could help. But here are my thoughts about the problem: Try measuring this voltage on the pin 3 and on the resistor's pin to see if you get the same spike voltage. Try making connections (pin 3 to transistor base & transistor emitter to GND) as short as possible.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but why not connect Q1 to +12VDC and a series resistor between Q1 emitter and Q2 base? That way Q2 can go into saturation resulting in a lower voltage drop across it and a brighter lamp.

Comment: Oh I used a TIP31C so no need to worry about Q1 and Q2 and the resistor in between them.

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused =(

Comment: I'm thankful for all your kind help and advice. Since I have no access to the necessary troubleshooting equipments right now, please bare with me as I can only select one answer that sounds the most comprehensive to me.

Comment: Just a random thought ...The capacitor gets charged to Vcc instead of 2/3 Vcc and hence the output shoots to above the required level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf).

- <intermezzo>Chapter 10: A bypass capacitor is highly recommended from VCC to ground pin; ceramic 0.1 μF capacitor is sufficient.
- Figure 4 shows that at \$I_{OH} = \dfrac{V_{output} - V_{base}}{R_{B}} = \dfrac{4V - 1.4V}{1\text{k}\Omega} = 3.6 \text{mA}\$ the voltage drop at the output is expected to be approximately 1.4V. This explains the voltage at the top of the pulse.
- Consider the internal circuit is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NE555_Internal_Circuit.svg The only thing I can think of that explains the overshoot to above Vcc is the base-emitter capacity for the top output darlington, combined with some barely dampened paracitic inductance in the wiring that briefly swings output above Vcc. The base to emitter capacity of the output darlington will be charged to approximately 0.7V (emitter voltage of the driver tranistor) when the output is low (, switching to high) and the other volt or so would be parasitic ringing due to capacity and inductance.
- The diode will clamp parasitic ringing voltage to about 0.7V above Vcc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the "spikes" are there because that's where the 555's output voltage is supposed to be, but something's pulling it down.

If you've got a 7805 running the 555 and [555] pin 3 drops down to 2V, then - assuming a good 555 and 7805 - either the 7805's input is dropping below the 7805's regulating threshold or the TIP31's base resistor's resistance is way too small.

If you're using your 12V supply as the input to the 7805 and the load pulls it down enough, that could be the problem.

The first thing I'd do, though, would be to check the base resistor and make sure it's not too small.

If it isn't, the next thing I'd do would be to put my scope across the 7805's input in order to rule that out, and if it's not the problem I'd still connect a BFC across the 7805's input and 100nF directly across 555 pins 1 and 8.  The BFC, just because, and the 100nF because the 555 has horrible shoot-through when it switches. If it *is* the problem, then a stiffer 12V supply is probably the solution.

Comment: BFC? <padding.>

Comment: @jippie  BFC stands for Big Fat Capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Mine was identical. I used a 33nf cap on pin3 to gnd. This did change my "On Time" and "Off Time" a tad but I just switched the pots out to higher values.